# How to make Collision physics grass?

Tags: particles, physics

Is it possible to have a character walk cycle interact with an object(s) like grass or foliage in blender?

Example from unreal engine:

https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.9040-2/41364949_2072967026047843_7831866438984925184_n.mp4?_nc_cat=0&efg=eyJybHIiOjgzOCwicmxhIjo5ODEsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoic3ZlX3NkIn0%3D&oh=36d5714f2fc7675b9c6c21cf42db2f81&oe=5B96E6E3

Comment: Yest it's possible.

Comment: Everything that is possible in almost any other program is possible in blender